# The results of the autoencoder code's functional API (my implemention) are different from the results of Sequential (example code in the textbook)

Tags: autoencoder, functional-api

In ch17 of the textbook 'hands on machine learning' by Aurélien Geron, the results of the functional API of the autoencoder code (which I implemented myself) are different from the results of Sequential (example code in the textbook).

The code below is an example code from Textbook ch17.

```
# https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml3/blob/main/17_autoencoders_gans_and_diffusion_models.ipynb
import tensorflow as tf

tf.random.set_seed(42)  # extra code – ensures reproducibility on CPU

encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)])
decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)])
autoencoder = tf.keras.Sequential([encoder, decoder])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.5)
autoencoder.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)

import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

m = 60
X = np.zeros((m, 3))  # initialize 3D dataset
np.random.seed(42)
angles = (np.random.rand(m) ** 3 + 0.5) * 2 * np.pi  # uneven distribution
X[:, 0], X[:, 1] = np.cos(angles), np.sin(angles) * 0.5  # oval
X += 0.28 * np.random.randn(m, 3)  # add more noise
X = Rotation.from_rotvec([np.pi / 29, -np.pi / 20, np.pi / 4]).apply(X)
X_train = X + [0.2, 0, 0.2]  # shift a bit

history = autoencoder.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=500, verbose=False)
codings = encoder.predict(X_train)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
plt.plot(codings[:,0], codings[:, 1], "b.")
plt.xlabel("$z_1$", fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel("$z_2$", fontsize=18, rotation=0)
plt.grid(True)
save_fig("linear_autoencoder_pca_plot")
plt.show()

[![linear_autoencoder_pca_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN2VI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN2VI.png)
```

The code below is my conversion of this example code into a functional API.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model
input1 = Input(shape=3)
x = Dense(2, activation='linear', name="intermediate")(input1)
x = Dense(3, activation='linear')(x)
model_autoencoder_funcAPI = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=x)
optimizer1 = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.5)
model_autoencoder_funcAPI.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer1)
history_funcAPI = model_autoencoder_funcAPI.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=501)
layer_name = 'intermediate'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=model_autoencoder_funcAPI.get_layer(layer_name).output)
codings_autoencoder_funcAPI = intermediate_layer_model.predict(X_train)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
plt.plot(codings_autoencoder_funcAPI[:,0], codings_autoencoder_funcAPI[:, 1], "b.")
plt.xlabel("$z_1$", fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel("$z_2$", fontsize=18, rotation=0)
plt.grid(True)
save_fig("ch17_linear_autoencoder_pca_plot_funcAPI")
plt.show()
[![ch17_linear_autoencoder_pca_plot_funcAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uuat.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uuat.png)
```

The results of the two codes are different. Where is the problem?

Thank you.

When implemented with the functional API code, I expected the same results as the results of the Sequential code.

================================================================
Solved!
Following user3128's advice, I added tf.random.set_seed(42) before building the model of the second code, and the result was the same as that of the first code.

Comment: Try setting the random seed again before you build the second model. I think that would ensure the random initialisation of weights for the second model will match that of the first model.

Comment: @user3128 Thank you bro. I added tf.random.set_seed(42) to the beginning of the second code and got the same result! Thanks to your comment, I learned more about TF.

Comment: My pleasure @IKAHN, glad I could assist.